# Updating sqlite3 API

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

I want to update/upgrade the standard Leopard install of Sqlite3 to >3.5 to use the new sqlite_xxx_v2 methods from a Cocoa project.

I can't seem to find any information on how to do this. Does anyone have any tips or a site that outlines the update procedure.

Also is 3.5+ supported on the iPhone. I understand it's embedded so shouldn't be an issue...

Comment: Please stop editing the tag. I know it SHOULD be Objective-C but the popular tag on here is objectivec.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want to do is grab the amalgamation sources from http://sqlite.org/download.html .  Then just compile that into / add it to your project.  You don't want to replace the system sqlite- that'll have unintended consequences in other applications.  Plus, I'm pretty sure the system sqlite isn't a stock sqlite... Apple has probably made their own modifications to it that core data relies on.

You can read up on the amalgamation stuff here: http://sqlite.org/amalgamation.html , but in short: '''The amalgamation is a single C code file, named "sqlite3.c", that contains all C code for the core SQLite library and the FTS3 and RTREE extensions'''

I'd also suggest not using the sqlite calls directly, they weren't designed to be used that way (says the author of sqlite).  Instead, there are a number of cocoa wrappers out there, including fmdb: http://code.google.com/p/flycode/source/browse/trunk/fmdb/ (which I wrote) :)

-gus

Answer (score 4):

You don't really want to upgrade the system version of SQLite on Mac OS X.  The reason is that all Mac OS X software is qualified against the versions of the packages that it includes, as built by Apple's build process.  Installing a different version of a package, or even building the same version yourself but doing so slightly differently than Apple does, may result in a system that behaves unexpectedly.

Finally, if you embed a newer version of SQLite — or any Open Source library or framework included with Mac OS X — into your own application, you should be sure to integrate the Darwin changes for it from Apple's public source site.  That way you can be sure you'll get as close to the same behavior as possible from the library you've built yourself as the version Apple ships, which is especially important when it comes to functionality like file locking in databases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe i've updated my version, but it's currently at 3.4.2, and i'm able to use the new methods with the current version.

And i'm running 10.5.5 with the latest (public) iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It would likely be easier to just drop the library into your project and link it in from there.